# What is the size limit for .r file extension size?

Tags: r, rscript, r-extension

What is the max file size limit for .r extension file now?

I read that it has 5MB limit, is it still the same? How does that change, will it be different from OS to OS or R version to version.

Reference: [RStudio maximum file size reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783838/rstudio-maximum-file-size-reached)

I'm very new to R, can someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no documented limit for the maximum file size or R code files. In fact, R will be able to deal with anything that’s even remotely reasonable. But for what it’s worth a 5 MiB source code file is *not* reasonable. If you actually have such files, I strongly suggest removing the large data that’s declared inside it, and moving it to a proper data file instead: separate your code and data. Actual code will never be this big.

As for *editing* such a file, different code editors have different limits for the size of files they deal well with. Again, having such a big code file is plain unreasonable, so not many code editors bother catering to this use-case, and even though few editors have a hard-coded limit, interactively editing such large files may not work.